Which cooling pad brands are trustable?
I have a 17.3 HP Omen 17-ap0xx laptop. Currently I'm using some old cooling pad that doesn't quite fit the size of my laptop.
I bought a few random no-name Chinese cooling pads in the past but their quality wasn't too satisfying. They randomly lose/break parts, such as the plastic regulation of angle. And the current one I have says it's made for 17.3 but it's few cm too small from all sides.
I am looking for a cooling pad brand/model meeting those criteria:

solid that will last for years of regular usage
fitting the 17.3 size very well
either as powerful as it can be through USB 3.0 or connected to power socket with a cable and including a battery
not too overpriced. 100$ would be the reasonable maximum for me let's say

Optionally:

designed in a way to collect as little dust/dirt/hair as possible (e.g. with some dust net/filter)

Does anything like this exist? Almost all of the ones that I see on Amazon and similar shopping sites are 20-50$ Chinese ones, often with weird brand names.
